# Heroku Django deployment is successful but the application url is showing "Application error"

Tags: django, heroku

I am able to deploy to create and deploy the Django app on Heroku. My app runs locally. But when I run heroku open I get the default error message

```
 An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.
```

wsgi.py

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from whitenoise.django import DjangoWhiteNoise

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "allistic_server.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
application = DjangoWhiteNoise(application)
```

Procfile

```
web:gunicorn server.wsgi --log-file
```

requirements.txt

```
Django==2.0.8
djangorestframework==3.9.1
gunicorn==19.7.2
whitenoise==3.6
```

heroku logs --tail

```
2019-03-05T19:14:22.539357+00:00 heroku[run.5495]: Awaiting client
2019-03-05T19:14:22.621479+00:00 heroku[run.5495]: Starting process with command `python3 manage.py migrate`
2019-03-05T19:14:30.032541+00:00 heroku[run.5495]: State changed from up to complete
2019-03-05T19:14:30.012744+00:00 heroku[run.5495]: Process exited with status 0
2019-03-05T19:14:32.734812+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=allistic-server.herokuapp.com request_id=8ad9d0a4-c449-4d43-8c0d-dbca27057c15 fwd="1.186.161.14" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-03-06T03:48:06.561682+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `bash` by user nedheesh.hasija@gmail.com
2019-03-06T03:48:12.189344+00:00 heroku[run.5469]: Awaiting client
2019-03-06T03:48:12.352258+00:00 heroku[run.5469]: State changed from starting to up
2019-03-06T03:48:42.200755+00:00 heroku[run.5469]: State changed from up to complete
2019-03-06T03:48:42.208643+00:00 heroku[run.5469]: Error R13 (Attach error) -> Failed to attach to process
2019-03-06T03:48:42.208643+00:00 heroku[run.5469]: Process exited with status 128
2019-03-06T03:49:06.415742+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `python3 manage.py makemigrations server` by user nedheesh.hasija@gmail.com
2019-03-06T03:49:11.116008+00:00 heroku[run.8566]: State changed from starting to up
2019-03-06T03:49:10.945200+00:00 heroku[run.8566]: Awaiting client
2019-03-06T03:49:10.978874+00:00 heroku[run.8566]: Starting process with command `python3 manage.py makemigrations server`
2019-03-06T03:49:15.768377+00:00 heroku[run.8566]: State changed from up to complete
2019-03-06T03:49:15.755742+00:00 heroku[run.8566]: Process exited with status 0
2019-03-06T03:49:27.418851+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `python3 manage.py migrate` by user nedheesh.hasija@gmail.com
2019-03-06T03:49:32.142089+00:00 heroku[run.4691]: Awaiting client
2019-03-06T03:49:32.162472+00:00 heroku[run.4691]: Starting process with command `python3 manage.py migrate`
2019-03-06T03:49:32.288884+00:00 heroku[run.4691]: State changed from starting to up
2019-03-06T03:49:37.323528+00:00 heroku[run.4691]: State changed from up to complete
2019-03-06T03:49:37.313173+00:00 heroku[run.4691]: Process exited with status 0
2019-03-06T03:50:31.399736+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=allistic-server.herokuapp.com request_id=626bda41-2cdc-44ce-95f1-f06440bb84a8 fwd="1.186.161.14" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-03-06T03:50:31.727399+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=allistic-server.herokuapp.com request_id=c1ea577e-a38f-487b-bf0a-557d1494155f fwd="1.186.161.14" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-03-06T03:50:31.732747+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=allistic-server.herokuapp.com request_id=00a45ba6-bf19-4a9f-8ce2-f41e585ae165 fwd="1.186.161.14" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Comment: What is project name? is it  just 'server' ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "allistic_server.settings")
```

I can see that you project is called as allistic_server, but in the procfile you have mentioned 'server.wsgi' which is not a valid path. Change this

```
web:gunicorn server.wsgi --log-file
```

to

```
web:gunicorn allistic_server.wsgi --log-file
```